# Returning struct from function in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to return a struct from one function to another for use with an API. The function is to reduce repeating my code in other places in my API that I am developing.

I'm getting the below error:

> cannot use getProjectLocations(params) (type []ProjectLocation) as type []ProjectLocation in assignment

Code below:

```
func GetProject(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)["uuid"]

    type ProjectLocation struct {
        UUID     string `json:"uuid"`
        Location string `json:"location"`
        Primary  bool   `json:"is_primary"`
    }

    type Project struct {
        UUID           string            `json:"uuid"`
        Owner          null.String       `json:"project_owner"`
        Name           string            `json:"project_name"`
        Locations      []ProjectLocation `json:"locations"`
    }

    q := `SELECT
            p.uuid,
            p.project_owner,
            p.project_name,
            p.project_type,
            p.project_status,
            p.created_date,
            p.created_by,
            p.last_modified,
            p.last_modified_by
        FROM
            projects p
        WHERE p.uuid=$1 LIMIT 1;`

    rows, err := global.DB.Query(q, params)
    global.CheckDbErr(err)

    var project Project
    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(
            &project.UUID,
            &project.Owner,
            &project.Name,
        )
        global.CheckDbErr(err)
    }
    project.Locations = getProjectLocations(params)

    rows.Close()
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(project)
}


func getProjectLocations(uuid string) []ProjectLocation {

    var Locations []ProjectLocation
    q := `SELECT uuid,location,is_primary FROM project_locations WHERE project_uuid=$1`
    rows, err := global.DB.Query(q, uuid)
    global.CheckDbErr(err)
    for rows.Next() {
        var location ProjectLocation
        err = rows.Scan(
            &location.UUID,
            &location.Location,
            &location.Primary,
        )
        Locations = append(Locations, location)
    }
    return Locations
}
```

I believe I'm returning a `[]ProjectLocation` struct to the get project function, so I'm just a little confused as a beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func GetProject(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)["uuid"]

    type ProjectLocation struct {
        UUID     string `json:"uuid"`
        Location string `json:"location"`
        Primary  bool   `json:"is_primary"`
    }

    // ...
}

func getProjectLocations(uuid string) []ProjectLocation {
    // ...
}
```

`type ProjectLocation` is local to `func GetProject`.